# Is it sometimes not appropriate to use << on ActiveRecord associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

Sometimes this works, and sometimes it doesn't:

```
class Foo
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar
  belongs_to :foo
end

foo = Foo.create
bar1 = Bar.create
bar2 = Bar.create

foo.bars << [bar1, bar2]
```

The fix is to assign them individually:

```
foo.bars << bar1
foo.bars << bar2
```

**updated**:

in the cases i'm experimenting with, `foo` and the `bar`s are not new objects.

I haven't see a pattern in when it does or doesn't work. What's more, it seems like how rails deals with mass assignment (`attr_accessible`) here is odd. If I have code in place to raise an exception if mass assignment is attempted (to help me catch bugs during development), it doesn't work. But if I'm not raising those exceptions, it does work, even though `foo_id` is not on the `attr_accessible` list in either case.

Comment: When you say "new" object, do you mean an instance of `Bar` which has not yet been saved to the database?

Comment: yeah, `bar.new_record? == true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the syntax `foo.bars << [bar1,bar2]`. Regarding the `<<` method as defined on a has_many association, the Rails [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) says:

> **collection<<(object, …)**
>
> Adds one or more objects to the
>   collection by setting their foreign
>   keys to the collection’s primary key.
>   Note that this operation instantly
>   fires update sql without waiting for
>   the save or update call on the parent
>   object.

That may give you some clues as to the (apparently) inconsistent behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Normally if you do "<< [x, y]" you don't push x and y to the array but rather a new array containing x and y (making it a multidimensional array):

```
> test = Array.new
=> []
> test << [1, 2]
=> [[1, 2]]
```

You might want to use "<< x << y" instead:

```
> test = Array.new
=> []
> test << 1 << 2
=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: This is exactly right, I don't know why you got a vote down. (I think it should be required to leave a comment with a vote down.) Anyway, hmm, you're right, and I used `<<` like that elsewhere, so why does `<<` work on associations at all in some cases? Maybe in the case where the `Foo` object doesn't have any `bars` to begin with?

Comment: There's no reason why `<<` wouldn't work on a `has_many` association - even if the parent object has no elements in the collection - as long as you're only appending one object into that collection, as Michael pointed out.

Comment: John, to be honest I cannot explain why it worked in some cases. Imho the << ist most convenient for adding objects to a has_many association.

Answer (score 1):

For newly created objects, I'd recommend using the `has_many` association helper methods `build` or `create`:

```
foo = Foo.create
bar1 = foo.bars.create  # saves the record
bar2 = foo.bars.build   # does not save the record
bar2.save!              # actually creates the object
```

These helpers can take a hash of attributes, just like regular `create` and `new` - the only difference is they automatically set up the association for you.

If the Bar object you are trying to add to `foo` already exists, my preference would be to set the association in the bar object:

```
foo = Foo.create   # alternately Foo.find(1)
bar = Bar.find(1)  # alternately Bar.new, but then use Foo.bars.build
bar.foo = foo
bar.save!
```

This way, it's a lot easier to track down problems, e.g. you can easily handle a validation error. The only difference with `<<` is it keeps `foo.bars` up to date without reloading it - so if you need `foo.bars` to be immediately up to date with full list of bars (the old bars and the newly associated bars), you might want to use `<<`.

As a final footnote, you can also use the `build` helpers to create the whole thing at once:

```
foo = Foo.new
bar1 = Foo.bars.build
bar2 = Foo.bars.build
foo.save!          # saves foo, bar1, and bar2 in one transaction,
                   # provided they are all valid
```

Comment: This is a great overview of these concepts, but does not actually address my question :-)

Comment: @John: Michael covered the problem with using `<<` with an array as an argument, but  considering I almost never use `<<` with an association (and have been doing Rails for years), I wanted to cover what I do instead of using `<<`. Your question was also fairly vague, IMHO, so I covered a wide array of issues here.

Comment: you're right… my question didn't actually even demonstrate a case where it does not work. if/when i encounter a case i'll update this question.